# Регулярные выражения Java номер телефона

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как написать

```
String pattern =;
```

для образца номеров?

```
String pattern = "^*(\\(\\+?d{2}\\)|\\.)*[1-9](\\d{2}-)(\\d{3}-)\\d{3}$";
```

НЕ работает.

Comment: `d{2}` находит два символа `d`. Попробуйте `s.matches("\\((?:\\+55)?\\d{2}\\)\\s*\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}")`. См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/4OQCmT/1).

Comment: https://ihateregex.io/expr/phone

Answer (score 0):

```
    String pattern = "^(\\((\\+55)*\\d{2}\\)\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})$";
    System.out.println("(+5522)22-222-222".matches(pattern)); //true
    System.out.println("(22)22-222-222".matches(pattern)); //true
    System.out.println("(22)22-222222".matches(pattern)); //false
```

Comment: `(+55+55+55+55+55+5521)22-222-222` - валидный номер для данного выражения